# Can I have a single #+TBLFM for multiple org tables?

Tags: org-table

I have multiple tables like below in an org file, but all having identical #+TBLFM lines. Is it possible to have just one #+TBLFM and have all these tables use it?

```
#+NAME: IOC
|  Rate | Units |  Amount |  Charges | Time             |
|-------+-------+---------+----------+------------------|
| 170.3 |    -6 | -1021.8 | -0.86853 | [2018-05-28 Mon] |
| 174.1 |     6 |  1044.6 | -0.88791 | [2018-05-31 Thu] |
|-------+-------+---------+----------+------------------|
| Total |     0 |    22.8 | -1.75644 |                  |
#+TBLFM: $3=$1*$2
```

(The original #+TBLFM has a large number of simple formulae. Currently if I have to change it, I copy and yank to every place.)

Comment: AFAIK, unfortunately no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of the lisp code at the end of this answer you can define a file-local list `org-table-buffer-local-formulas` of replacements within org-table formulas which are active during the command `org-table-recalculate`.
Each replacement is a cons `(REGEXP . NEWTEXT)` of a regular expression string `REGEXP` that should match the string you want to replace and the new text string `NEWTEXT` that replaces the match.

The following example demonstrates how you can define `org-table-buffer-local-formulas` and how you can use the replacements in org table formulas.

```
* Section with tables
You can use the replacements in ~org-table-buffer-local-formulas~
in org table formulas:

| first column | second column | third column |
|--------------+---------------+--------------|
|            1 |             2 |            4 |
|            2 |             4 |            8 |
#+TBLFM: {TBLFM:FIRST}

A second table with the same formula:
|              |               |              |
| first column | second column | third column |
|--------------+---------------+--------------|
|            3 |             6 |           12 |
|            5 |            10 |           20 |
#+TBLFM: {TBLFM:FIRST}

The third table uses another formula from the list:
|              |               |              |
| first column | second column | third column |
|--------------+---------------+--------------|
|            3 |             9 |           36 |
|            5 |            15 |           60 |
#+TBLFM: {TBLFM:SECOND}


* Local Variables :noexport:
Local Variables:
org-table-buffer-local-formulas: (("{TBLFM:FIRST}" . "$2=2*$1::$3=2*$2") ("{TBLFM:SECOND}" . "$2=3*$1::$3=4*$2"))
End:
```

There follows the lisp code you need to make the above example work.
You can install that lisp code in your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html).

```el
(defun cmdbufmod-prepare (bufmod-list &optional start bound)
  "Prepare buffer for `cmdbufmod' with modifications BUFMOD-LIST.
See `cmdbufmod' for the format of BUFMOD-LIST.
If START is a buffer position the search for the regular expressions in BUFMOD-LIST
starts there. Otherwise it starts at `point-min'.
Optional BOUND limits the search.
Return the list of original text sections.
Each text section is a cons of an insertion marker and the old text
that needs to be restored there."
  (unless start (setq start (point-min)))
  (let (original-list)
    (save-excursion
      (dolist (bufmod bufmod-list)
    (let ((place (car bufmod))
          (newtext (cdr bufmod)))
      (goto-char start)
      (while (if (functionp place)
               (funcall place bound)
              (re-search-forward place bound t))
        (setq original-list
          (cons (cons (set-marker (make-marker) (match-beginning 0))
                  (match-string 0))
            original-list))
        (replace-match (propertize (if (functionp newtext)
                       (funcall newtext)
                     newtext)
                       'cmdbufmod t))))))
    original-list))

(defun cmdbufmod-cleanup (original-list)
  "Restore original text sections from ORIGINAL-LIST.
See the return value of `cmdbufmod-prepare' for the structure of ORIGINAL-LIST."
  (cl-loop for interval being the intervals property 'cmdbufmod
       if (get-text-property (car interval) 'cmdbufmod)
       do (delete-region (car interval) (cdr interval)))
  (cl-loop for original in original-list do
       (goto-char (car original))
       (insert (cdr original))))

(defun cmdbufmod (bufmod-list fun &rest args)
  "After applying BUFMOD-LIST to current buffer run FUN with ARGS like `apply'.
BUFMOD is a list of buffer modifications. Each buffer modification
is a cons \(PLACE . NEWTEXT).
PLACE can be a regular expression or a function.
If PLACE is a function it should search for the next place to be replaced
starting at point. It gets the search bound as an argument,
should set match-data like `re-search-forward',
and return non-nil if a match is found.
If PLACE is a regular expression it is treated like the function
\(lambda () (re-search-forward PLACE nil t))

NEWTEXT can be a replacement string or a function.
A function should return the string for `replace-match'."
  (let (original-list)
    (unwind-protect
    (progn
      (setq original-list (cmdbufmod-prepare bufmod-list))
      (apply fun args))
      (cmdbufmod-cleanup original-list))))

(defvar-local org-table-buffer-local-formulas nil
  "List of buffer local table formulas.
Each element is a cons of a regexp and a formula (sequence).
The text matching the regexp is replaced by the formula sequence
when the table is iterated.")

(defun org-table-get-stored-formulas-buf-loc (oldfun &rest args)
  "Replace buffer local table formulas when calling OLDFUN with ARGS."
  (cmdbufmod org-table-buffer-local-formulas oldfun args))

(advice-add 'org-table-recalculate :around #'org-table-get-stored-formulas-buf-loc)
```

Comment: This works for me. Thanks. It will be useful to add that  'M-x normal-mode'  can be used to reload local variables after editing.

Comment: @KarthikeyaKameswaran You can make `hack-local-variables` interactive and use that instead of `normal-mode` for re-reading local variables: `(defun hack-local-variables-make-interactive (&rest _args)
  "Just add the 'interactive'-specification to 'hack-local-variables'."
  (interactive))

(advice-add 'hack-local-variables :before #'hack-local-variables-make-interactive)`

Comment: @KarthikeyaKameswaran Is your question still open or can you accept my answer? I want to avoid that this question is repeatedly bumped to the emacs.sx homepage.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. I upvoted instead of accepting. Still learning sx. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible.  However, you could write a babel src block which takes such tables as input and outputs what you want, including another table but not necessarily so.  You could then invoke the babel block using call_XXX(tablename).